# How is where clause in SQL evaluated?

Tags: sql

I have thought of this a lot and never found the answer. I have found my self in situations where i haven't known how the conditions in a where clause of a SQL query is evaluated. To be sure, i have always used parentheses to make it more readable, and simple to understand. I consider it to be good practice to use parentheses sometimes to increase readability, even if it maybe isn't needed.

Consider the following query

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
WHERE name='Anton' 
  AND lastname='Gildebrand' 
   OR age > 18 
  AND country='Sweden'
```

I imagine that this query is actually equal to

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
WHERE name='Anton' 
 AND (lastname='Gildebrand' OR (age > 18 AND country='Sweden'))
```

Is this correct? Or how is the conditions evaluated?
Does it differ from different database engines?

Comment: And this is why use of `OR` should also mean use of parenthesis; just for the readability.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE name='Anton' AND lastname='Gildebrand' OR age > 18 AND country='Sweden'
```

Is equal to:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE (name='Anton' AND lastname='Gildebrand') OR (age > 18 AND country='Sweden')
```

Sources: [TSQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx), [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html), [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/conditions001.htm#i1034834), [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/sql-syntax.html#SQL-PRECEDENCE-TABLE)

Comment: Are you ***sure*** about this? [Operator precedence](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/operator-precedence.html) is `AND` then `OR`

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk: yes, `AND` is evaluated before `OR`. I updated the answer with some links.

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk . . . Double yes. This is explicit in the ANSI standard, as well as the convention in many programming languages.

Comment: Cool, didn't think of that one. Everyone seems to agree with your answer so i will accept it as answer :)

Answer (score 3):

If you are talking about `and` and `or`, then in absence of parenthesis `and` is evaluated first.  The same as `*` and `+` in math.

These rules are not dependent on SQL implementations.

Comment: That link, by the way, makes no mention at all of operator precedence, that I can see. A critical failure of that documentation, IMO. (and pretty much par for the course with w3schools.) Your answer is correct, though.

Comment: I agree with @Andrew, this answer is correct but the link is pretty much useless.

Comment: @ypercube - removed the link